# If condition issue in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

When i execute the script, always the first condition is executed. Even the
script is worth for second condition.

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("jSuccess")).isDisplayed())
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("jSuccess")).click();
        System.out.println("Clockedin Successfully....");
    }
else if (driver.findElement(By.id("jError")).isDisplayed())
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("jError")).click();
        System.out.println("User already clockedin");
    //  ul.getclockout().click();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please evaluate the 'loop' in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have typo where you have written **`loop`** instead of **`condition`**

You can try `size` function on `findElements`

Also, since you have used `if` and `else if` so only one of them will execute

```
if (driver.findElements(By.id("jSuccess")).size()>0) {  
       driver.findElement(By.id("jSuccess")).click();
        System.out.println("Clockedin Successfully....");
    }
else if (driver.findElements(By.id("jError")).size()>0)  {   
        driver.findElement(By.id("jError")).click();
        System.out.println("User already clockedin");
    //  ul.getclockout().click();
    }
```

// If you want both statements should be executed based on condition evaluation then you can use like below by removing `else`

```
if (driver.findElements(By.id("jSuccess")).size()>0) {  
       driver.findElement(By.id("jSuccess")).click();
        System.out.println("Clockedin Successfully....");
    }
if (driver.findElements(By.id("jError")).size()>0)  {   
        driver.findElement(By.id("jError")).click();
        System.out.println("User already clockedin");
    //  ul.getclockout().click();
    }
```

Comment: @Infern0 - I answered based on statement with condition instead of loop. I have made edit in the question once approved that will be corrected. Your concern is very much valid. Thanks

Comment: @Infern0 - If you read main description of question it says - _**"If condition issue in selenium webdriver"_** .

Comment: answer is based on description of problem. and description was saying " always the first loop is executed"

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `if-else` statement. If the `if` condition is true, the `else` will not get evaluated. If you want both to be evaluated, then remove the `else` and just use two `if`s.

Sounds like you want this...

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("jSuccess")).isDisplayed())
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("jSuccess")).click();
    System.out.println("Clocked in Successfully....");
}

if (driver.findElement(By.id("jError")).isDisplayed())
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("jError")).click();
    System.out.println("User already clocked in");
}
```